# Creating a difference variable for each set of matched pairs, mutate_at() two sets

Tags: r, matching, dplyr

Let's say I have 10 variables from 2010:
A_2010, B_2010, C_2010, ..., A_A_2010, ect.

and 10 variables from 2020:
A_2020, B_2020, C_2020, ..., A_A_2020, ect.

I want to find the difference between 2020 and 2010 variables, for each variable. So in the end I'd like 10 variables:
A_diff, B_diff, C_diff, ..., A_A_diff, ect.

which is basically just `A_2020 - A_2010`, `B_2020 - B_2010`, and so on.

How can I do this on R with `dplyr`? I considered using `mutate_at` but I don't think I can use two 'sets' of variables. I also considered using `mutate`, as such:
`mutate(diff = vars(ends_with("_2020")) - vars(ends_with("_2010")))`
But obviously this won't work since mutate only makes one variable. Plus, I only want the difference between matching pairs, not cross differences.

What is the simplest way to do this using `dplyr`? I would also be ok with doing a function.

Comment: It would be easier and faster to help if you include an example data along with expected output.

Comment: they're all numerical values between 0 and 1. percentages to be exact.

Comment: That doesn't help. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

The dummy data I created looks like this:

```
   id     A_2010      B_2010       C_2010       A_2020     B_2020      C_2020
1   1 -1.4106479 -0.41316193  0.671434592  0.431175305  0.9530425 -0.07645398
2   2 -0.4233896 -0.55844324  0.351625958 -0.835936648 -1.8954344  0.77046246
3   3 -1.1210037 -0.72905447  0.394883881  0.722913328 -0.1387928 -2.73316817
4   4  0.7292334 -0.27776558  0.618026393 -0.083015341 -0.2535384 -0.66328672
5   5 -0.1212647 -0.36964042 -0.126540747 -0.008974603 -0.3462768  0.21037482
6   6  0.5674501  0.03823422 -0.002472146 -1.013204719  0.1534576  0.46734696
7   7  0.8097872  1.29604921  1.116411440  0.243686906  0.4341491  0.66321482
8   8 -0.6830225  0.49210937  1.158570926  0.430689144  0.5482753 -0.87753792
9   9 -1.2455627  0.22572320  0.125511143 -1.280150826 -2.0216185  0.05846329
10 10 -0.4060474 -1.09270201  0.319908580  0.517562785 -2.0227615 -1.26608836
```

Here is the code I think is you need:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df10 <- df %>% select(id, contains('2010')) %>% gather(key = 'Var10', value = 'Val2010', -id)
df20 <- df %>% select(id, contains('2020')) %>% gather(key = 'Var20', value = 'Val2020', -id)
dfAll <- cbind(df20, df10[,-1])
dfAll$diff <- dfAll$Val2020-dfAll$Val2010
```

This is the end result:

```
> head(dfAll)
  id  Var20      Val2020  Var10    Val2010       diff
1  1 A_2020  0.431175305 A_2010 -1.4106479  1.8418232
2  2 A_2020 -0.835936648 A_2010 -0.4233896 -0.4125471
3  3 A_2020  0.722913328 A_2010 -1.1210037  1.8439171
4  4 A_2020 -0.083015341 A_2010  0.7292334 -0.8122487
5  5 A_2020 -0.008974603 A_2010 -0.1212647  0.1122901
6  6 A_2020 -1.013204719 A_2010  0.5674501 -1.5806548
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the two set of columns directly.

```
#column names of 2010
var_2010 <- grep('2010', names(df), value = TRUE)
#column names of 2020
var_2020 <- grep('2020', names(df), value = TRUE)
#create new columns
new_col <- paste0('diff_', gsub('\\d|_', '', var_2010))

#subtract
df[new_col] <- df[var_2020] - df[var_2010]
```